# C# code to do bulk Update/Insert SharePoint list Item using Rest API call

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to do bulk update in sharepoint list by looping through item ids as in the code below. However it just update successfully for the first time.
Second update gives error as  "Response status code does not indicate success: 403".

I have followed this url
[C# code to Update SharePoint list Item using Rest API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252915/c-sharp-code-to-update-sharepoint-list-item-using-rest-api-call)

```
Uri uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"]);
            using (var client = new SPHttpClient(uri, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]))
            {
                var listTitle = "sp_sample";
                var itemId = 1;
                var itemPayload = new { __metadata = new { type = "SP.Data.sampleListItem" }, Title = "Phani", Place = "Hyderabad" };
                for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    itemId = i;
                    var endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{1}')/items({2})", uri, listTitle, itemId);
                    var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    headers["IF-MATCH"] = "*";
                    headers["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
                    client.ExecuteJson(endpointUrl, HttpMethod.Post, headers, itemPayload);
                    Console.WriteLine("Task item has been updated");

                }
```

Please do share if we have any inbuilt function for bulk update/insert. 
Or any code to do bulk update or insert.

Any guide would be helpful.

Comment: The 403 means your request doesn't have permission, which version you're using? SharePoint on-premise/online? the authentication will be different.

Comment: @Lee_MSFT , yes that's bit confusing as well. If you see, I have mentioned in the beginning, I am able to do for single Item but If I am looping in for multiple Ids, it throwing me 403 error. Probably I am incorrectly looping it or I am missing some inbuilt function which can help in bulk update/insert. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did test and find the issue caused by duplicate request header, try update method below.

```
public JObject ExecuteJson<T>(string requestUri, HttpMethod method, IDictionary<string, string> headers, T payload)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            switch (method.Method)
            {
                case "POST":
                    var requestContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));
                    requestContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=verbose");
                    var Digest = RequestFormDigest();
                    DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", Digest);
                    if (headers != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var header in headers)
                        {
                            DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                        }
                    }
                    response = PostAsync(requestUri, requestContent).Result;
                    break;
                case "GET":
                    response = GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Method {0} is not supported", method.Method));
            }

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return String.IsNullOrEmpty(responseContent) ? new JObject() : JObject.Parse(responseContent);
        }
```

Comment: I understand as we need to clear the header earlier in order to have a fresh one. Just wanted to know, if we have some function or way in which we can avoid the for loop to update each item. is it possible to get all the updated data in json format (which I can can do) and in one header request, all data gets updated correctly??